# Is there any info about after Watchmen?

Tags: dc, watchmen

So at the end of *Watchmen* things aren't exactly your fairy-tale ending and I personally found the story kind of inconclusive. Were there any ever comics or books or any material that told the story after the events of *Watchmen*?

Comment: The world was at peace, united against the perceived alien threat. That was the whole point in Rorshach's death - he refused to live in a world based on a lie.

Comment: @Omegacron But his final actions also made it clear that the lie would be revealed. His journal was going to the media.

Comment: @Axelrod - I'm a bit late on this one, but I highly doubt Rorschach's story would be believed by most people. After all, to the public at large he was a convicted (and paranoid) vigilante whereas Ozymandias was the world's most respected super-hero. It would be a lot like Batman (the urban legend version, not the "respected member of the JLA" version) claiming that Superman was behind an alien attack. There would obviously be some people who believed it, but the rest of the world would chuck it up to a conspiracy theory and never believe it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No there weren't.

However, [Alan Moore revealed to Wired in 2010](http://www.wired.com/underwire/2010/07/alan-moore-watchmen) that DC had offered him the rights to *Watchmen* back, if he would agree to prequel and sequel projects:

> “They offered me the rights to *Watchmen* back, if I would agree to some
>   dopey prequels and sequels.” [...] “So I just told them that if they
>   said that 10 years ago, when I asked them for that, then yeah it might
>   have worked,” he said. “But these days I don’t want *Watchmen* back.
>   Certainly, I don’t want it back under those kinds of terms.”

The same article also contains a response by DC Comics co-publishers Dan DiDio and Jim:

> “Watchmen is the most celebrated graphic novel of all time. Rest
>   assured, DC Comics would only revisit these iconic characters if the
>   creative vision of any proposed new stories matched the quality set by
>   Alan Moore and Dave Gibbons nearly 25 years ago, and our first
>   discussion on any of this would naturally be with the creators
>   themselves.”

In recent years they have published the ***[Before Watchmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Before_Watchmen)*** comic series, a prequel to *Watchmen*.

There are also vague plans for a TV series, as reported by [Collider](http://collider.com/watchmen-tv-series-hbo-zack-snyder/),[Variety](http://variety.com/2015/tv/news/watchmen-series-zack-snyder-1201607567/), and [Coming Soon](http://www.comingsoon.net/tv/news/618725-hbo-considering-a-watchmen-series-with-zack-snyder).

Comment: http://screenrant.com/watchmen-tv-show-hbo-zack-snyder/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDDHHrt6l4w

Answer (score 3):

2017's *[Doomsday Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_Clock_(comics))* takes place in the world of *Watchmen*, seven years later.

> Ozymandias's plot was revealed after Rorschach's journal was published and the world is now on the brink of nuclear war again.

This and 2017's *[The Button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Button_(comics))* serve to link the Watchmen universe with the current mainstream DC universe.

Comment: Is the series good? Would you recommend it? I'd like to read up on it but don't know where to start (with all the _Rebirth_) stuff involved.

Comment: @gallifreyan I haven't had a chance to read them yet.